# How to find good quality questions on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I love this site for the opportunity it gives for learning and asking questions, but sometimes I find it hard to find something interesting to read and think about or solve. There's so much noise. By browsing the questions page I rarely find the stuff that interests me.

What I usually do is go to the users tab, then find users with high reputations scores and then go read questions and answers they gave.

Do you have some other strategies for finding interesting reading on this site?

Comment: The strategy you already gave is the most reliable one.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use tags. You can set the tags that you are specifically interested in. Questions with those tags will then be highlighted.

You can also search for questions on a specific tag. As an example if you are normally using C# you could step out of the box by looking at Haskell questions.

I have my personal interests, but I also like to read questions outside my interests, as it can challenge your view of the programming world.

Don't be afraid of learning something new and especially reading opinions of users that you disagree with. The really good thing about SE is that people actually argue their case and do so without being offensive.